# systemd timer every 8 hours

Tags: linux, systemd-timer

I am fairly new using systemd timers, and I am having some issues.

I am trying to schedule a script that runs daily, every 8 hours, at 6 AM, 2 PM, and 10 PM. The time starts correctly, and it shows the next scheduled time to run (which it does), but then it never seems to run the 3rd (or any other) time. What am I doing wrong?

I have this in my timer:

```
[Unit]
Description=Run every 8 hours
Requires=script.service

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*-*-* 03,11,19:00:00
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

I have also tried this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Run every 8 hours
Requires=script.service

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*-*-* 03,11,19:00:00
OnUnitActiveSec=1d
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

And this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Run every 8 hours
Requires=script.service

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*-*-* 03:00:00
OnCalendar=*-*-* 11:00:00
OnCalendar=*-*-* 19:00:00
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

Service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Renews Kerberos ticket every 8 hours
After=network-online.target firewalld.service
Wants=network-online.target script.timer

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/kdestroy
ExecStart=/usr/bin/kinit -R -V user@mydomain.org -k -t /etc/krb5.keytab
IOSchedulingClass=best-effort

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
'''
```

Comment: Is the timer staying active after its first run? Your **OnCalendar** settings are correct (I tested the first edition with *systemd-analyze calendar "*-*-* 03,11,19:00:00"*), so maybe there's something wrong with the service that it's calling.

Comment: Yes, the timer does stay active and even runs the next job on time. It is the 3rd one that never runs.

Comment: It doesn't matter what time I start the timer on, always runs 2 times, then stops.

Comment: Post the script.service; add to your question.

Comment: Completely unreadable. Add to your question, please.

Comment: Edited question and added service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I believe the problem is with the **script.service** file. According to the `systemd.timer` man page:

```
DESCRIPTION
       Note that in case the unit to activate is already active at the time the timer elapses it is not restarted, but simply left running. There is no concept of spawning new service instances in this case. Due to this, services
       with RemainAfterExit= set (which stay around continuously even after the service's main process exited) are usually not suitable for activation via repetitive timers, as they will only be activated once, and then stay
       around forever.
```

Remove the `RemainAfterExit=` line and you should be good to go.

Comment: That's appears like it could be the issue. I will remove it and try it again. Thanks for the feedback. I will circle back around to this post after this sits enough time to renew. :)

Comment: Timer is running as expected now. Appreciate the assist!